# How to set Fetch data into Array using JavaScript and set data into innerHTML Bootstrap card

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, fetch-api

I have Fetch method like this:

```
async function sendApiRequest() {
    let APP_ID = "f61bb958";
    let APP_Key = "7c465e19d8e2cb3bc8f79e7a6e18961e"
    let INPUT_VALUE = document.getElementById("inputRecipe").value;
    console.log(INPUT_VALUE)
    fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_Key}&q=${INPUT_VALUE}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById("ripeCard").innerHTML = `
       <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
           <img src="${data.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
           <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>         
      </div>
            `
        })
}
```

The API returns data as follows:

```
count: 7000
from: 0
hits: Array(10)
0:
recipe: {uri: "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_1b6dfeaf0988f96b187c7c9bb69a14fa", label: "Pizza Dough", image: "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/284/2849b3eb3b46aa0e682572d48f86d487.jpg", source: "Lottie + Doof", url: "http://www.lottieanddoof.com/2010/01/pizza-pulp-fiction-jim-lahey/", …}
__proto__: Object
1:
recipe: {uri: "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_0209cb28fc05320434e2916988f47b71", label: "White Pizza", image: "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/dfe/dfe2e44c86334a3a3a5f774dda576121.jpg", source: "Food52", url: "https://food52.com/recipes/40095-white-pizza", …}
__proto__: Object
2:
recipe: {uri: "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_77db6e25dffe1836d4407cf4575f0141", label: "Chorizo, caper & rocket pizza", image: "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/7fe/7fee72cbf470edc0089493eb663a7a09.jpg", source: "BBC Good Food", url: "http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/1506638/chorizo-caper-and-rocket-pizza", …}
__proto__: Object
3:
recipe: {uri: "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_c9bf37296a0126d18781c952dc45a230", label: "Pizza Frizza recipes", image: "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/94a/94aeb549b29ac92dced2ac55765f38f9", source: "Martha Stewart", url: "http://www.marthastewart.com/284463/pizza-frizza", …}
__proto__: Object
4:
recipe: {uri: "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_b2ebad01df2a319d259c2d3f61eb40c5", label: "Margarita Pizza With Fresh Mozzarella & Basil", image: "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/d72/d72d1b7dd988e3b340a4b90ed3d56603.jpg", source: "Big Girls Small Kitchen", url: "http://www.biggirlssmallkitchen.com/2010/06/cooking-for-others-bff-pizza-party.html", …}
__proto__: Object
5:
recipe: {uri: "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_1b25671a32284038b57ad8b49c44af68", label: "Grilled BLT Pizza recipes", image: "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/2ac/2ac98d88117ff8f2327d302ab290b164", source: "Food Republic", url: "http://www.foodrepublic.com/recipes/grilled-blt-pizza-recipe/", …}
__proto__: Object
6: {recipe: {…}}
7: {recipe: {…}}
8: {recipe: {…}}
9: {recipe: {…}}
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
more: true
q: "pizza"
to: 10
```

And I need to set Fetch data to innerHTML Bootstrap card,
but to do that I need to set fetch data into an Array.
How can I set my Fetch data an Array and how to set Fetch data to innerHTML Bootstrap card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need from the API are the recipes, so the API returns them in the `hits` property. The `hits` property is an array of recipes

The properties in the recipe object are; SO you can pick what you need,

```
['uri', 'label', 'image', 'source', 'url', 'shareAs', 'yield', 'dietLabels', 'healthLabels', 'cautions', 'ingredientLines', 'ingredients', 'calories', 'totalWeight', 'totalTime', 'cuisineType', 'mealType', 'dishType', 'totalNutrients', 'totalDaily', 'digest'];
```

```js
async function sendApiRequest() {
    let APP_ID = 'f61bb958';
    let APP_Key = '7c465e19d8e2cb3bc8f79e7a6e18961e';
    let INPUT_VALUE = document.getElementById('inputRecipe').value;
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_Key}&q=${INPUT_VALUE}`);
    const data = await response.json();

    document.getElementById('ripeCard').innerHTML = ''; // Resetting the content of the element

    // Iterating through the array of recipes and destructuring the result object to give only the recipe property
    data.hits.forEach(({recipe}) => {
        document.getElementById('ripeCard').innerHTML += `
       <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
           <img src="${recipe.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">${recipe.label}</h5>
           <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
        <a href="${recipe.url}" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>         
      </div>`;
    });
}

sendApiRequest();
```

```html
<input id="inputRecipe" value="pizza">
<div id="ripeCard"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should break each task into a separate function. Also, a debounce function wrapper for your search input will make searching more efficient. I borrowed the debounce function from [Josh W Comeau](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/snippets/javascript/debounce/) website snippet.

Anyways, your API data contains a key called `hits`. This contains an array of objects with a single key called `recipe`. This object holds values to information including the `label`, `calories`, `ingredients`, etc. It is up to you what data you want to display.

**Note:** The data appears paged and the example below does not support paging. This would be up to you to implement.

```js
const API_URL = 'https://api.edamam.com';
const APP_ID = "f61bb958";
const APP_KEY = "7c465e19d8e2cb3bc8f79e7a6e18961e"

const cards = document.querySelector('#recipe-cards');

const main = async() => {
  const searchInput = document.querySelector('#input-recipe');
  searchInput.addEventListener('input', searchRecipes);
  triggerEvent(searchInput, 'input');
};

const cardAsHtml = ({ recipe }) => `
  <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img src="${recipe.image}" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">${recipe.label} (${recipe.calories.toFixed(0)} cals)</h5>
      <p class="card-text"><ul>${recipe.ingredientLines.map(line =>
        `<li>${line}</li>`).join('')}</ul></p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>    
    </div>
  </div>
`;

// https://www.joshwcomeau.com/snippets/javascript/debounce/
const debounce = (callback, wait) => {
  let timeoutId = null;
  return (...args) => {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(() => {
      callback.apply(null, args);
    }, wait);
  };
};

const updateRecipes = (data) => {
  cards.innerHTML = '';
  data.hits.forEach(hit => cards.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cardAsHtml(hit)));
};

const searchRecipes = debounce((ev) => {
  const query = document.getElementById('input-recipe').value;
  sendApiRequest(API_URL, APP_ID, APP_KEY, query)
    .then(updateRecipes)
}, 250);

const sendApiRequest = async(url, id, key, query) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${url}/search?app_id=${id}&app_key=${key}&q=${query}`);
  return response.json();
};

// http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#trigger_custom
const triggerEvent = (el, eventName, data = {}) => {
  let event;
  if (window.CustomEvent && typeof window.CustomEvent === 'function') {
    event = new CustomEvent(eventName, {detail: data});
  } else {
    event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    event.initCustomEvent(eventName, true, true, data);
  }
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
};

main();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<label>Search: <input type="text" id="input-recipe" value="cake" placeholder="Cake, pie, etc."/></label>
<div id="recipe-cards"></div>
```